# How to assign array value in array on golang

Tags: go

how to assign array on requestor in resultProducts, so i can assign value []requestor and output the value

here is my code

```
result, err = or.orderProductRepo.GetProductDetailRequest(ctx, tx, request.OrderID)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("SQL error on UseCase GetDetailRequest => GetProductDetailRequest", err)
    helper.CommitOrRollback(tx, err)
    return &result, err
}

resultProducts, err := or.orderProductRepo.GetListProductRequestor(ctx, tx, request.OrderID)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("SQL error on UseCase GetDetailRequest => GetListProductRequestor", err)
    helper.CommitOrRollback(tx, err)
    return &result, err
}
getListRequestFor, err := or.orderProductRepo.GetListRequestFor(ctx, tx, request.OrderID)
if err != nil {
    log.Println("SQL error on UseCase GetListRequestFor => GetListRequestFor", err)
    helper.CommitOrRollback(tx, err)
    return &result, err
}
for _, v := range resultProducts {
    for _, j := range getListRequestFor {
        v.Requestor = append(v.Requestor, models.ListProductRequestor{
            OrderID:            j.OrderID,
            IDRequestor:        j.IDRequestor,
            ProductID:          j.ProductID,
            RequestorName:      j.RequestorName,
            RequestorEmail:     j.RequestorEmail,
            InformationDetails: j.InformationDetails,
            StatusCode:         j.StatusCode,
            Status:             j.Status,
            IsInventory:        j.IsInventory,
        })
    }
    for _, data := range resultProducts {
        // how to assign []requestor value into getListRequestFor so i can assign data like in -> result.Product = resultProducts
    }

    result.Product = resultProducts
}

return &result, nil
```

}

// how to assign []requestor value into getListRequestFor so i can assign data like in -> result.Product = resultProducts

Comment: Please take the Tour of Go to learn about fundamental types.